# Mesh Line of Sight Babylonjs

Tags: javascript, websocket, sensors, babylonjs

I am working on a catch and run game, and I have a cat and rat meshes along with a height map that creates walls for me. My objective is to develop a game that two competitors write algorithms and communicate with server using websocket to catch/run. Simply I want to send users their line of sight so they can run/catch without crashing into walls.

As far as I know Gazebo simulation program has LazerScan that has distance array to the obstacles with decided view of angle such as pi radian is used for deciding which was to go with no knowledge of the world. How can I achieve this goal? How can I get the distances to obstacles which provided with some decided angle of view?

I want to do this in that way, because any indexing can be wrong for situations like roundoff errors may occur, but any suggestions are welcome. Please consider the fact that I will send this info to users and expect them to understand quickly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and see how and what to ask. HINT: post effort and CODE in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try creating a frustum for your player (basically 6 planes) and then rely on mesh.getBoundingInfo().boundingBox.isInFrustum:
https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/2b6bd17eaaa5cecc04846d024156ae4d45974c9f/src/Culling/babylon.boundingBox.ts#L104